# Multiple audioplayers keep playing on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-player

I have an app on Flutter with different tabs and on each tab basically I have a different audioplayer. By the way I use the "audioplayers.dart" package.

When the user changes tab, I want the audioplayer to stop. So I put a stop() function in the dispose method.

However, sometimes this isn't working because of states issues.

I wonder if there is an easiest way by forbidding maybe an audioplayer to be play when the user is on another page ?

```
late AudioPlayer audioplayer;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    audioplayer = AudioPlayer(playerId: 'liked_musics');


    audioplayer.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration d) {
      setState(() => duree = d);
    });

    audioplayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((Duration d) {
      setState(() => position = d);
    });

    audioplayer.onPlayerCompletion.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        position = duree;
        statut = PlayerState.STOPPED;
      });
    });

  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    audioplayer.stop();
  }
```

Thank you for your help

Joffrey

Comment: why not put stop() in the block of code before player navigates to the nextpage instead of in dispose() ?.

Comment: Because my tabs are in another Class. 
Is there a way to call function between Classes ? I've heard about the Global Key method, but some people say it is not very safe...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [event bus package](https://pub.dev/packages/event_bus)

Sample pseudo code:

```html
class AudioStopEvent {
  int clickedTabPosition;

  AudioStopEvent(this.clickedTabPosition);
}

class BusHelper {
  static EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();

}

class YourTabPage{

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     BusHelper.eventBus.on<AudioStopEvent>().listen((event) {
    if(event.clickedTabPosition != currentPagePosition)
     audio.stop();
    });
   }
}

class YourTabManagementClass{

whenChangeTabPage(){
 BusHelper.eventBus.fire(new AudioStopEvent(clickedPagePosition)); }
}
```